# How do I check if data exists in my SQL table and if it doesn't insert the newer data?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My table is made up of 3 values-

- long
- short
- id

id is an auto increment int value and the rest are text.

My PHP script retrieves the latest version of a program every half an hour and stores it as long in an sql table. What I want is for the php script to check if the value is already in the table(i.e. there are no new versions). If it isn't I want it to insert the new data. 
**Just to make this clear I am not replacing the value "long". I am merely making a new value of it and 'id' is keeping a record of how many versions there have been.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the EXISTS Keyword.

```
INSERT INTO Table (Col1, Col2, Col3)
Values(?, ?, ?)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT Col1 FROM TABLE
WHERE Col1 = ? AND Col2 = ? AND Col3 =?)
```

You can work out which columns you actually need to test.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a *UNIQUE* index on the *long* column and use *INSERT IGNORE*:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO versions (long, short)
VALUES (?, ?)
```

If the key already exists MySQL will generate a warning (not an error) and will neither insert nor update any rows.